# How Can I Create an Object in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an object in javascript code like this. I need to do this object in flutter. How can I do same thing in flutter with below javascript code ?

```
var object = {
       tsSubCmds: [
             {
              entityType: "DEVICE",
              entityId: entityId,
              scope: "LATEST_TELEMETRY",
              cmdId: 10
              }
          ],
           historyCmds: [],
           attrSubCmds: [],
           entityDataCmds: []
};
var data = JSON.stringify(object);
```

I tried to do like this. but it did not work like this.

```
var data = '{ tsSubCmds: [{entityType: DEVICE, entityId: ' + dashboardId + ', scope: LATEST_TELEMETRY, cmdId: 10 }], historyCmds: [], attrSubCmds: [], entityDataCmds: []}';
data = jsonDecode(data);
var object = jsonEncode(data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var object = {
  'tsSubCmds': [
    {'entityType': "DEVICE", 'entityId': entityId, 'scope': 'LATEST_TELEMETRY', 'cmdId': 10}
  ],
  'historyCmds': [],
  'attrSubCmds': [],
  'entityDataCmds': []
};
```